# Why is Stack Overflow not using CSS media queries?

Tags: feature-request

As far as I know, CSS media queries are much better for everything. From sitespeed to SEO score, and of course it immediately shows the webpage as it should be when people start sizing the browser screen. I don't know if these things I've heard about CSS queries are right, so I figured I could best ask them here.

Might be an unrelated question, but I am really wondering :)

Comment: In terms of SEO score, SO have nothing to worry, considering that pretty much all of use can say that most of our problems are solved by googling end ending up there in the 3 top link.About responsiveness, i develop on my desktop, so I don't care about how SO looks on my mobile, since when i google for developping things, i'm on my desktop.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a mobile version. You can switch to it in the footer.

Comment: Yeah, ofcourse developing mostly happens on desktop. But shouldn't it be the goal of every webdeveloper (or designer) to have a fully responsive site for every device, even desktop?

Comment: @Pekka웃 that's true, stackoverflow is responsive. But why not use CSS media queries?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as it failed to actually answer your question. :) There’s previous discussion on why the desktop site is not (at least somewhat) responsive, but I can’t find it right now.

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210511/should-stack-overflow-be-redesigned-with-a-responsive-layout

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen no, that should **not** be the goal of every developer. Every developer should *consider* it, and decide whether the trade offs make sense for whatever they're working on. That's their job.

Comment: I’s a fair argument though that a programming Q&A site *should* be usable with the window at 50% or 33% width...

Comment: Well, looking at the votes I guess people are not agreeing with me...

Comment: "CSS media queries are much better for everything" Oh, if only it were that simple...

Comment: @BoltClock you added CSS media queries and now you have two problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responsiveness don't solve everything about mobile apps.

One thing it doesn't solve is the weight of the page:

- bandwidth
- size of JavaScript to execute once downloaded
- number of functionalities/links present on the page of desktop's version

If your site is pretty heavy and don't have an alternate mobile page loading then executing way less HTML/JavaScript/CSS than a mobile application, your site will be damn slow.

If you take a look at the mobile version (click on the `mobile` link at the bottom of the page). You'll see you won't have as much content than on desktop, "hot network question", "related tabs" are not available. Why? Because there isn't really the place for this. Furthermore it makes less code to execute on the mobile.

Mobile application/site's version when they're good are always a subset of the desktop version, because you just can't fit everything on it.

TL;DR CSS media queries are fine for different size of screen, even tablet at home I'd say, but aren't enough for mobiles if your site is quite big.

Comment: His argument is that the desktop site should be responsive, though. Which is hard to completely refute.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Strangely, I don't find it bothering on SE site, while i strongly hate those blogs with the default width of bootstrap fixed width container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I do not always understand why sidebars mostly have to go when browsing on mobile versions, you gave me a good and nice answer. I don't get it why people downvote my question, but I guess I just asked a stupid question. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen voting/downvoting is special on Meta, unless you would have a -20 on 1h, you don't really need to bother. It just mean they don't agree with what you ask, not that you're question is low quality or whatever

Comment: @Walfrat Ooh, so that's why. Thanks for pointing that out for me :p